# How can display message after entering value in textbox with the help of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some code in jsfiddle. i have one textbox in table and i want to check if user insert 3000 then i want to display message like yes you are correct

my code for jquery is

```
    $("#text10").keyup(function(){
        $("#text10").blur();
        $("#text10").focus();
});
$("#text10").change(function(){
    var assetname = document.getElementById('text10').value;
    if(assetname =$3000)
        {
           //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
             $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("CONGRATULATION ! YOU HAVE ENTERED APPROPRIATE BLOCKS FOR ACCOUNTING.");
        }
    else
    {
        $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("CONGRATULATION ! YOU HAVE.");
    }
});
```

here you can check my code - http://jsfiddle.net/vvQbm/5/

Please help

Comment: as always and saying it again.... **ID should always be unique** ..`ID="amt2"` multiple times

Comment: `if (this.value == '$3000') {...`

Comment: ^^^ If you had an element with that ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $("#text10").keyup(function(){
        $("#text10").blur(); // why you 'r using that?
        $("#text10").focus(); // why you 'r using that?
});
$("#text10").change(function(){
    var assetname = $(this).val();
    if(assetname =='3000')
        {
           //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
             $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("CONGRATULATION ! YOU HAVE ENTERED APPROPRIATE BLOCKS FOR ACCOUNTING.");
        }
    else
    {
        $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("CONGRATULATION ! YOU HAVE.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Really - `assetname ='3000'`

Comment: Lol, im still sleeping. You can edit this answer too, its better down vote and post this non constructive comment? Are you sure you trying to help the community? Or just make reputation?

Comment: Why would I start messing around with your answer, that's just bad form ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if(assetname =$3000) 
You are not comparing correctly,you need to use == for comparison
```

to

```
if(assetname =='$3000')
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvQbm/6/)